# Добавление элементов управления в проект WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем доброго времени суток. Работаю над проектом курсовой работы: разработка windows-приложения на языке C# в среде разработке Visual Studio 2017 с помощью WPF. На сайте (https://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/) я нашел архив с элементом управления от Torsten Mandelkow. Всё бы хорошо, но сколько бы я не мучился не смог его добавить в свой проект, помогите пожалуйста! Конкретно мне нужен BarChart, подскажите как его добавить в своё решение в виде элемента управления?

Comment: а существующий код показать?

Comment: Дело в том, что в данном архиве такое неприличное количество  пространств имен и классов, что я даже не знаю куда мне лезть!

Comment: Вам принципиально именно эти контролы использовать? Из NuGet нельзя что-нибудь похожее установить?

Comment: Не хотелось бы показаться больно капризным, но именно эти контролы отлично подходят к моему проекту как по дизайну, так и по функционалу (из описания).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Скачайте бинарники здесь: https://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/releases/view/106190 ссылка "Binaries.zip", извлеките из архива файл \Binaries\WPF\De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart.dll

Подключите его к проекту: щелкнуть правой по References - AddReference... - Browse - Browse... - Выбрать тот файл, поставить на нем галочку - OK

Теперь в разметке окна добавьте пространство имен:

```
xmlns:tm="clr-namespace:De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart;assembly=De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart"
```

Можно пользоваться, я взял класс `TestClass` и коллекцию `ObservableCollection<TestClass> Errors` из примера там же:

```
<tm:StackedBarChart>
    <tm:StackedBarChart.Series>
        <tm:ChartSeries SeriesTitle="Errors"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Errors}"
                        DisplayMember="Category"
                        ValueMember="Number"/>
    </tm:StackedBarChart.Series>
</tm:StackedBarChart>
```

Получилось вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выражаю Вам огромную благодарность. Тот файл мне больше нужен? Я его могу уже удалить или необходимо его держать недалеко от exe'шника?

Comment: Студия сама его скопирует в выходную папку, да он должен лежать рядом с exe вашего приложения

Comment: Нигде не самовольничал, а ошибка тут, как тут. Не пойму как добавить скриншот.

Comment: На любой хостинг картинок и ссылку сюда

Comment: https://ibb.co/fysmmb

Comment: А если собрать проект?

Comment: Не помогло. Я надеюсь, что "ссылки" - это то куда я должен был добавить библиотеку.

Comment: Создайте пустой проект и попробуйте сделать всё то же самое, если ошибка останется - скиньте куда-нибудь архив с проектом

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/N78x-K943R5dbV - не могу исправить самостоятельно и в новом проекте не получается

Comment: Я удалил сборку из References и добавил заново - сработало нормально. Непонятно почему, у вас было включено `EmbedInteropTypes=True` в свойствах сборки

Comment: А где вы это нашли?

Comment: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdjiO.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVw6f.png) и всё работает

Comment: А вы не знаете примерно такую же библиотеку, но только что бы после ее добавления в элементах был готовый контрол, с котором можно будет работать?

Comment: Зачем вам это? Рисовать контролы мышкой? Так проектировать я вам не рекомендую, добавляйте контрол в разметку и редактируйте свойства прямо в разметке, ну или в окне Properties

Comment: Пожалуйста подскажите как вы подключили sourse к графику

Comment: Скопировал определение класса `TestClass` и определение и код для заполнения коллекции `ObservableCollection<TestClass> Errors`, потом эта коллекция просто привязывается к `ChartSeries`: `ItemsSource="{Binding Errors}"` и указываются свойства из которых надо брать подписи и значения: `DisplayMember="Category" ValueMember="Number"`

Comment: Отправьте вашу сборку

Comment: http://rgho.st/8yDYqZZpp